# Excel validate by colors with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I need to check if a person (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) have authorization to use some product (A, B, C, D, E), so i have this:
[image: Check]

and have this authorizations table:

[image: Table]

so i need, after insert the letter and the number, have a Yes or No Authorization.

Comment: This is a website which **helps you write** your own VBA code. So, maybe you can share with us the code you have written thus far? Where exactly do you experience any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste the public function into a vba module in your workbook and then use it directly in your worksheet as a formula "getAuth(...)".

Parameters used:

- Letter: Range with the letter
- Number: Range with the number
- AuthRange: Range with the Authentication data (the table with the
  colors)
- YesColor: Range with the color used for Yes (uses the background color)

```vb
Public Function getAuth(Letter As Range, Number As Range, _
AuthRange As Range, YesColor As Range) As String
    Dim rng As Range
    With AuthRange
        Set rng = .Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(Number, .Columns(1), 0), _
            WorksheetFunction.Match(Letter, .Rows(1), 0))
        getAuth = IIf(rng.Interior.Color = YesColor.Interior.Color, "Yes", "No")
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Work like a charm, thks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this directly into your workbook (**more details below**) :

```
Public Function Get_Auth(ByVal User As String, ByVal Product As String) As String
Dim A()
A = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("DB_Prod").Value

For i = LBound(A, 1) To UBound(A, 1)
    For j = LBound(A, 2) To UBound(A, 2)
        If A(i, 1) <> User And A(1, j) <> Product Then
        Else
            'If interior is different of red (use macro recorder to get your own color reference)
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(i, j).Interior.Color <> 255 Then
                'If interior is different of green
                If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(i, j).Interior.Color <> 5287936 Then
                    'Not handled
                Else
                    Get_Auth = "Yes"
                End If
            Else
                Get_Auth = "No"
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Function
```

**First** you need to set a name for your authorization table (I used "DB_Prod"), or specify the address of the table ($A$1:$C$10) and change the Sheet name into the code :

`A = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("DB_Prod").Value`

Then activate **macro recorder and change 2 cells color, one to green, one to red to identify the specific colors** that you use and change it into the code :

`If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(i, j).Interior.Color <> 5287936` (green color)

Then you can **type directly into your workbook** : `=Get_Auth(A2,C1)`

Enjoy!

Comment: Hello, thks for help, but went i type directly into workbook : =Get_Auth(x;y) the Excel don't recognize the formula

Comment: Did you place this in a regular module? Not in a Sheet or in ThisWorkbook?

Comment: look my answer, i put in answer because the picture